Java application unable to connect to local Solr server instance using 'Http2SolrClient', but succeeds using 'HttpSolrClient'
Following are the application setup used in our Java application:
JRE: Oracle openjdk 11.0.4 2019-07-16
Deployment environment: Apache Tomcat 9.0.38
Apache Solr server: 9.5.0 (single server running on localhost, SSL not enabled, no default config altered)
Java client library for Solr: solr-solrj-9.5.0
Now, the old Java code (we are now migrating from Apache Solr 5.4.1) used to look like this:
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient solrServer = new HttpSolrClient.Builder("http://localhost:8983/solr/SOLR_HOME").build();
...
...
...
QueryResponse res = solrServer.query(query);

Whereas, the new code looks like this:
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient solrServer = new Http2SolrClient.Builder("http://localhost:8983/solr").withDefaultCollection("SOLR_HOME")
                    .withConnectionTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .withRequestTimeout(60000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build();
...
...
...
QueryResponse res = solrServer.query(query);

Where, 'SOLR_HOME' is the name of the Solr core. The problem now is that the old code works just fine, yet the new code using the new class 'Http2SolrClient' instead of the deprecated 'HttpSolrClient' does not. The reason I added the timeouts is because otherwise it takes forever for the UI web request to ultimately fail and show the error message to the UI. We get the below exception:

org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Total timeout 60000 ms elapsed
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient.request(Http2SolrClient.java:591)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:255)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.query(SolrClient.java:927)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.query(SolrClient.java:940)
at com.xxx.yyy.ref.solr.SwiftMsgSearchQueryBuilder.fetchAllRecords(SwiftMsgSearchQueryBuilder.java:155)
at com.xxx.yyy.ref.solr.SwiftMsgSearchQueryBuilder.executeQuery(SwiftMsgSearchQueryBuilder.java:182)
at com.xxx.yyy.inf.dbutils.AbstractQueryBuilder.query(AbstractQueryBuilder.java:333)
at com.xxx.yyy.ref.web.base.XenosAbstractQueryController.executeQuery(XenosAbstractQueryController.java:593)
...
...
...
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Total timeout 60000 ms elapsed
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpDestination$RequestTimeouts.onExpired(HttpDestination.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpDestination$RequestTimeouts.onExpired(HttpDestination.java:591)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.CyclicTimeouts.onTimeoutExpired(CyclicTimeouts.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.CyclicTimeouts$Timeouts.onTimeoutExpired(CyclicTimeouts.java:197)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.CyclicTimeout$Wakeup.run(CyclicTimeout.java:294)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
1 more

Now, I've already verified on my system using this cURL utility for Windows that the Solr instance running on my localhost does indeed support HTTP2 protocol. So that begs the question: where is our Solr setup failing us? Thanks in advance to all those who'd take the time to respond and try to help out.
